# How do we prove that the initial velocity is equal to final velocity relative to centre of mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

In elastic collision it is stated that the initial velocity relative to centre of mass is equivalent to final velocity of centre of mass of the same object. How do we prove that?

Comment: Conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the two pertinent conservation laws for elastic collisions: kinetic energy and momentum. Remember that momentum is a vector.

In the center of mass frame, the total momentum is zero. That will get you started. Do the work for two particles first.

As an aside you should try to show the total momentum is zero in the CoM frame by example by taking two different mass particles with different velocities colliding head-on in the lab. Calculate the velocity of the CoM, find the  velocities of the particle relative to the CoM, then find the momentum.

Answer (score -1):

logically in the frame of centre of mass the accn of body is zero so momentum is conserved and as mass has not  changed initial velocity is equal to final velocity in frame of centre of mass

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! It is not clear what this answer adds over the already existing answer by BillN. Please try to make contributions that actually *add* something to the post.